# filter django queryset by onetoone model field property

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

i have two model classes and they are related by OneToOneField like here

```
class Book(models.Model):
      is_user_ok = models.BooleanFiled()
class Mybook(models.Model):
      book = models.OneToOneField( Book, related_name="Book", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

now i want make a queryset filter by book field property. but here `book.is_user_ok`
cannot be used. how can i make this queryset filter?

```
queryset = Mybook.objects.filter(book.is_user_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking a common problem, what you really want to do is `related_name__column_name` in filter, in your case you can try

`queryset = Mybook.objects.filter(book__is_user_ok=True=True)`

> Reference from official docs:
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

double underscore is used for joins as you have already set the relationship in model variety of joins work here, it is used as per the model relation.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wrong syntax. Replace `(book.is_user_ok=True)` with `(book__is_user_ok=True)` The problem is, using '.' instead of '__'. Thats the correct syntax when dealing with another model class